# SSL with mariaDB not working without MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT: FALSE

Tags: ssl, mariadb, ssl-certificate

I have a working SSL setup between `symfony 6` on `PHP 8.1` application and `mariadb 10.9` but it only works if I add the option `!php/const PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT: false`

This is for me only a temporary fix but could not find the root of the issue.

I have experimented a lot with different CN because I read it could be this but can't make it work.

my dev is ip `127.0.0.1` (docker container is `database`) and my prod server has an `ip only` too. I do not have any domain name

here is `gencerts.sh`

```
OPENSSL_SUBJ="/C=US/ST=California/L=Santa Clara"
OPENSSL_CA="${OPENSSL_SUBJ}/CN=fake-ca"
OPENSSL_SERVER="${OPENSSL_SUBJ}/CN=fake-server"
OPENSSL_CLIENT="${OPENSSL_SUBJ}/CN=fake-client"

openssl genrsa 2048 > certs/ca-key.pem
openssl req -new -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 3600 \
        -subj "${OPENSSL_ROOT_CA}" \
        -key /certs/ca-key.pem -out /certs/ca-cert.pem
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -days 3600 -nodes \
        -subj "${OPENSSL_SERVER}" \
        -keyout /certs/server-key.pem -out /certs/server-req.pem
openssl rsa -in /certs/server-key.pem -out /certs/server-key.pem
openssl x509 -req -in /certs/server-req.pem -sha256 -days 3600 \
        -CA /certs/ca-cert.pem -CAkey /certs/ca-key.pem \
        -set_serial 01 -out /certs/server-cert.pem
openssl verify -CAfile /certs/ca-cert.pem /certs/server-cert.pem
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -days 3600 -nodes \
        -subj "${OPENSSL_CLIENT}" \
        -keyout /certs/client-key.pem -out /certs/client-req.pem
openssl rsa -in /certs/client-key.pem -out /certs/client-key.pem
openssl x509 -req -in /certs/client-req.pem -sha256 -days 3600 \
        -CA /certs/ca-cert.pem -CAkey /certs/ca-key.pem \
        -set_serial 01 -out /certs/client-cert.pem
openssl verify -CAfile /certs/ca-cert.pem /certs/client-cert.pem
```

error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] (trying to connect via (null))
```

`docker log` is

```
2022-09-13 14:26:34 3 [Warning] Aborted connection 3 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '192.168.16.3' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
```

Comment: "Doesn't work"  isn't exactly a detailed error description...

Comment: @georg well "it only works if I add the option !php/const PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT:" is adding some detail, it is probably the same old "can't disable host name verification only" problem again that we already talked about in passing a while ago?

At Sam: I assume CN=fake-server is not the real host name that your PHP code uses for the server it wants to connect to?

Comment: "my prod server has an ip only too" answers my previous question about CN=fake-server being the real server host name used to connect. Two suggestions: either add a "IP fake-server" entry in the clients /etc/host and then use that name to connect, so that it matches the CN in the server cert subject, or use the actual server IP as CN when generating the server certificate

Comment: Related PHP bug report: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68344

Comment: @HartmutHolzgraefe: CN is deprecated, should be in SAN

Comment: @GeorgRichter that does not solve the problem that there is no option to turn off server host name verification only with mysqlnd though, for that it is not relevant whether the server name to check against is retrieved from x509v1 CN or from x509v3 SAN extension?

Comment: @HartmutHolzgraefe  I added error messages in question. I do not have any domain name just ip for my database server. From your suggestion in prod I should use the real ip but in docker should I use 127.0.0.1 or container name ? I tried both; nothing solves the issue